Deno 2.0 install local npm package from folder
Been experimenting with deno 2.0. I can't find a way to do a simple 'deno add' or 'deno install' of a local npm folder (package). Is this not possible in deno?
Searched all of the docs and tried getting help from the deno team, to no avail.

Yeah, same here. It seems Deno2 can't grab local dependency from the package.json: Not implemented scheme 'file' in package.json

^ This is being tracked at the following GitHub issue: denoland/deno#18474

It's hard to believe deno doesn't support this. It's the first documented approach in npm. Very strange.
